# jquery live search

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if someone can help me out with a jquery issue I am having. The code below is a snippet i found on another post but I am looking to adapt it slightly

the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#criteria').on("input", function(e) {
    var words = $(this).val().toLowerCase().match(/\S+/g);
    if (!words) {
        $('.links li').show();
    } else {
        $('.links li').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var show = false;
            $.each(words, function(i, word) {
                show = show || Boolean(~text.indexOf(word));
            });
            $(this).toggle(show);

        });
    }
});

}); // end document ready
```

and the HTML

```
<ul class="links">
<li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now this works like it should, it looks for a match in the input field and filters the results accordingly by hiding links where there is no match. What I want to do instead of using toggle is add a class to the li elements where there is no match to make them fade using css.

I have tried using $(show).addclass(); instead of $(this).toggle(show); but it doesnt seem to do anything, im assuming because the variable show is not used but when i tried to a class of effect to variable show it does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have one small suggestion . why you have used large coding to
search particular `text` in `li`. just simply you can use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to search element based on text.
use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) like below.

your requirement can do by below coding.

```
$('#criteria').on("input", function(e) {
     $('.links li:not(:has(a:contains("link 1")))').toggleClass("className");

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VwCTp/1/)

Comment: where you have link 1 is it possible to have say the value of the input box ("link 1") become (input.val()) instead

Comment: going to accept this answer as I managed to get what i wanted using the method you had suggested, theres a basic demo http://jsfiddle.net/VwCTp/59/ of what I am going to expand on

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.toggleClass()` add create a class with css with display:none / opacity:0.0

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/